# Why spark lazy loading slower than wildcarding or passing folders in array?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset which is partitioned and written to s3 as a set of JSON files.

The partitions structure is:
uid - usually <20 partitions. Int, possible values: 1-100, 70000-70100, 80000-80100
type - String 2 partitions
date - As a usual date. Usually in a range of 2 months.
hour - Obvious 24 partitions.

There is one JSON file inside a partition. The common amount of data ~30GB

When I pass the root folder as it took **~3 min 30 sec** to print schema of files.

```scala
val df = spark.read.json("s3://path/to/root/folder")
df.printSchema()
```

When I pass the root folder but perform initial filtering it also took **~3 min 30 sec**.

```scala
val df = spark.read.json("s3://path/to/root/folder")
  .filter(col("uid") === 1 || col("uid") === 80004)
df.printSchema()
```

I reduced loading time to **2 min 31 sec** by wildcarding all partitions

```scala
val df = spark.read.json("s3://path/to/root/folder/uid=*/type=*/date=*/hour=*")
df.printSchema()
```

I tried to bracket all needed uid's it worked. I reduced loading time to **~34secs**

```scala
val df = spark.read
  .option("basePath", "s3://path/to/root/folder")
  .json("s3://path/to/root/folder/uid={1,80004}") 
df.printSchema()
```

I also tried to add needed folders in an array and got the same time.

```scala
val df = spark.read
  .option("basePath", "s3://path/to/root/folder/")
  .json("s3://path/to/root/folder/uid=1/type=OW/date=2019-07-24/",
        "s3://path/to/root/folder/uid=1/type=OW/date=2019-07-25/",
        "s3://path/to/root/folder/
        ...
        "s3://path/to/root/folder/uid=80004/type=OW/date=2019-08-13")
```

I thought lazy loading should help me but it didn't. Could someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting faster time with wildcarding.. but for the explicit folders vs full data the time difference is probably due to the fact that the spark reader needs to do a full scan of all the data in order to infer the schema.  The schema inference step happens immediately when you call read because spark needs to know the schema to proceed and results in Spark executing actions under the hood for you.

You can try reducing the samplingRatio option from it's default of 1.0:

```scala
val df = spark.read.option("samplingRatio", "0.1").json("s3://...")
```

Or you can try explicitly specifying the schema:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(
    StructField("uid",IntegerType,true) ::
    StructField("type",StringType,true) :: 
    ... :: Nil
)

val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("s3://.....")
```

The predicate push-down optimization where it only loads some partitions of your data does happen, but it won't happen until you execute an action against that loaded dataframe.  You can confirm this by running explain and looking at the Physical Plan like below, in the PartitionFilters section:

```
df.filter($"uid" === "1" && $"type" === "bob").explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter (('uid = 1) && ('type = bob))
+- Relation[key#70,key2#71,uid#72,type#73] json

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
key: string, key2: string, uid: int, type: string
Filter ((uid#72 = cast(1 as int)) && (type#73 = bob))
+- Relation[key#70,key2#71,uid#72,type#73] json

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (((isnotnull(uid#72) && isnotnull(type#73)) && (uid#72 = 1)) && (type#73 = bob))
+- Relation[key#70,key2#71,uid#72,type#73] json

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) FileScan json [key#70,key2#71,uid#72,type#73] Batched: false, Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/.../test/stackoverflow], PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(uid#72), isnotnull(type#73), (uid#72 = 1), (type#73 = bob)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<key:string,key2:string>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Reducing `samplingRatio` didn't have an effect. Explicitly specifying the schema reduced loading time to **1 min 45 sec** which is better than wildcarding but slower than bracketing.

Comment: How many total json files are there across all partitions?  S3 can be slow to list files where than is a large number, and the partition discovery code probably needs to list all the files to figure out what partitions are present.

Comment: 1 per partition. ~2000 files, single file about 0.5mb